# How to call a script from within a script

Tags: bash, shell, unix

So the question Im trying to figure out is to call a script from within a script to do this question

> Perform the following transactions in a single script called, june_trans.sh. Assume the balance equals zero to start. You can use any filename of your choice for this question as long as the value stored in the file is initialized to zero.
>
> ```
> deposit <filename> 1200
> debit <filename> 390
> debit <filename> 29
> debit <filename> 8
> deposit <filename> 120
> debit <filename> 50
> debit <filename> 40
> debit <filename> 20
> debit <filename> 9
> deposit <filename> 1200
> debit <filename> 200
> debit <filename> 9
> debit <filename> 50
> deposit <filename> 1200
> debit <filename> 129
> debit <filename> 80
> debit <filename> 9
> debit <filename> 20
> ```
>
> display account balance.
>
> What is the remaining balance?

I'm supposed to create this script using the previous scripts that were created such as

**deposit.sh**

```
amount=$(cat $1)
echo $(($amount + $2)) > $1
```

**debit.sh**

```
amount=$(cat $1)
echo $(($amount - $2)) > $1
```

**show_balance.sh**

```
amount=$(cat $1)
echo $amount
```

So my question is how can I call upon these scripts to create the script called june_trans.sh?

This what I did the long way but I need a more efficent way of doing this question. And I cant use any if/loops statements when writing the script

```
amount=$(cat $1)
balance=$(($amount + 1200 - 390 - 29 - 8 + 120 - 50 - 40 - 20 - 9 + 1200 - 200 - 50 - 9 + 1200 -129 - 80 - 9 - 20))
echo $balance
```

Edit: Got the correct answer by running this:

june_trans.sh amount

Inside my main script

```
./deposit.sh $1 1200

./deposit.sh $1 1200

./deposit.sh $1 1200 

./deposit.sh $1 120

./debit.sh  $1 390

./debit.sh  $1 29

./debit.sh $1 8

./debit.sh $1 50

./debit.sh $1 40

./debit.sh $1 20

./debit.sh $1  9

./debit.sh $1 200

./debit.sh $1 9

./debit.sh $1 50

./debit.sh $1 129

./debit.sh $1 80

./debit.sh $1 9

./debit.sh $1 20

./show_balance.sh $1
```

and the output is 2677 which is correct but how can I run it more efficently by only calling each of three mini scripts inside my main script only once?

Comment: You run a script from another script the same way you run it from the terminal. `/path/to/deposit.sh filename amount`

Comment: You can also put the directory containing the script into your `$PATH`, and then just write `deposit.sh filename 20`

Comment: and I'll add *You run a script from another script the same way you run* **any command** from inside a script, assuming your PATH is set properly OR you use a fully-qualified path to your script (as described above). Good luck.

Comment: When you want to call `debit filename 500`, the script should be called `debit`,  not `debit.sh`

Comment: Hey can you check my edited post?